# App send notifications in background at a given time

Tags: android

I want to do a simply app that send notifications (in background) every day at different hour. I've searched how to do it on internet but i'm new to android programming and i don't understand a lot. So someone could help me, i don't want all the code but only a basic idea on how to do it. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up NotificationManager and AlarmManager.

Example:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
  public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

  }
}

private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

Code taken from: https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223